# return date values by multiple attributes

Tags: r

My apologies if this has already been asked somewhere.

I have two dataframes.

df1:

```
Account Name    Account Number  Product Annual Contract Value   Date
Customer A  50261601    Banana  10000   1/1/2015
Customer B  50208388    Orange  50000   2/1/2015
Customer A  55795702    Apple   25000   3/1/2015
Customer C  50217249    Pear    45000   4/1/2015
Customer A  50378835    Orange  12000   5/1/2015
Customer C  55123434    Banana  14000   6/1/2015
Customer A  50438332    Banana  7500    7/1/2015
Customer D  55131817    Peach   5600    8/1/2015
Customer F  53765467    Plum    25000   9/1/2015
Customer E  50990613    Banana  10000   10/1/2015
Customer D  53846150    Orange  18000   11/1/2015
Customer A  50234897    Apple   30000   12/1/2015
```

and df2:

```
Date    Product Account Sales
1/1/2015    Apple   55795702    500
2/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1000
3/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1500
4/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1000
5/1/2015    Apple   55795702    2000
6/1/2015    Apple   55795702    2500
7/1/2015    Apple   55795702    3000
8/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1001
9/1/2015    Apple   55795702    3500
10/1/2015   Apple   55795702    4000
11/1/2015   Apple   55795702    4500
12/1/2015   Apple   55795702    1002
```

What I am looking to do in R, is I want to see if customers are living up to their annual contract value in a given time frame.  So for this example, in df1 customer 55795702 signed an Apple contract on 3/1 for an annual value of $25K.  I want to find that customer in df2, find that product for that customer, then return the sum of the next three months of purchases to see if they are on track to purchase the annual value of $25K.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This may be close to what you are looking for. I modified your data for the purpose of this demonstration. Here you have two account numbers in both `df1` and `df2`, which are 55131817 and 55795702. First, I converted the data frames to data.table objects. Then, I converted Date to an Date object in both data sets. Then, I used `merge()` and get the data for the account numbers existing in both `df1` and `df2`. By this time, you have two columns for date. `Date.x` is from df1 and the other from df2. Using the columns, I identified the beginning of the contracts and get data for the following three months. Month that they signed in contract is removed. If the month is inclusive, you want to revise the code. This operation gives you row indexes for subsetting. The final operation was summarizing the data for each account number. I added `Value` so that you can track down how each customer has been doing so far.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]
setDT(df2)[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]

merge(df1, df2, by.x = "AccountNumber", by.y = "Account")[
    unlist(lapply(which(Date.x == Date.y), function(x){x + 1:3})), ][,
    list(whatever = sum(Sales), Value = Value[1L]), by = "AccountNumber"]

#   AccountNumber whatever Value
#1:      55131817    12000  5600
#2:      55795702     5500 25000
```

**DATA**

**df1**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "AccountName    AccountNumber  ProductAnnualContract Value   Date
CustomerA  50261601    Banana  10000   1/1/2015
CustomerB  50208388    Orange  50000   2/1/2015
CustomerA  55795702    Apple   25000   3/1/2015
CustomerC  50217249    Pear    45000   4/1/2015
CustomerA  50378835    Orange  12000   5/1/2015
CustomerC  55123434    Banana  14000   6/1/2015
CustomerA  50438332    Banana  7500    7/1/2015
CustomerD  55131817    Peach   5600    8/1/2015
CustomerF  53765467    Plum    25000   9/1/2015
CustomerE  50990613    Banana  10000   10/1/2015
CustomerD  53846150    Orange  18000   11/1/2015
CustomerA  50234897    Apple   30000   12/1/2015", header = TRUE)


    AccountName AccountNumber ProductAnnualContract Value       Date
 1:   CustomerA      50261601                Banana 10000 2015-01-01
 2:   CustomerB      50208388                Orange 50000 2015-02-01
 3:   CustomerA      55795702                 Apple 25000 2015-03-01
 4:   CustomerC      50217249                  Pear 45000 2015-04-01
 5:   CustomerA      50378835                Orange 12000 2015-05-01
 6:   CustomerC      55123434                Banana 14000 2015-06-01
 7:   CustomerA      50438332                Banana  7500 2015-07-01
 8:   CustomerD      55131817                 Peach  5600 2015-08-01
 9:   CustomerF      53765467                  Plum 25000 2015-09-01
10:   CustomerE      50990613                Banana 10000 2015-10-01
11:   CustomerD      53846150                Orange 18000 2015-11-01
12:   CustomerA      50234897                 Apple 30000 2015-12-01
```

**df2**

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "Date    Product Account Sales
1/1/2015    Apple   55795702    500
2/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1000
3/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1500
4/1/2015    Apple   55795702    1000
5/1/2015    Apple   55795702    2000
6/1/2015    Apple   55795702    2500
7/1/2015    Apple   55795702    3000
8/1/2015    Peach   55131817    1001
9/1/2015    Peach   55131817    3500
10/1/2015   Peach   55131817    4000
11/1/2015   Peach   55131817    4500
12/1/2015   Apple   55795702    1002", header = TRUE)

          Date Product  Account Sales
 1: 2015-01-01   Apple 55795702   500
 2: 2015-02-01   Apple 55795702  1000
 3: 2015-03-01   Apple 55795702  1500
 4: 2015-04-01   Apple 55795702  1000
 5: 2015-05-01   Apple 55795702  2000
 6: 2015-06-01   Apple 55795702  2500
 7: 2015-07-01   Apple 55795702  3000
 8: 2015-08-01   Peach 55131817  1001
 9: 2015-09-01   Peach 55131817  3500
10: 2015-10-01   Peach 55131817  4000
11: 2015-11-01   Peach 55131817  4500
12: 2015-12-01   Apple 55795702  1002
```

Comment: Thanks Jazzuro for the start. I get this error when I run the code? Can not match keys in x and y to automatically determine appropriate by parameter. Please set by value explicitly

Comment: @Tom I am not sure how your real data look like. You may have different column names. The other thing is that I use data.table version 1.9.6. If you have an old version, my code may not work.

Comment: Ah ok got it....I am stuck with version 1.9.4 and am unable to download the new update because of a work firewall.  Thanks for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tom Pleasure to help you. :)